# QTableView mouse double-click event

Tags: qt, double-click, qtableview

I have instance of QTableView. I want to open a dialog to edit data from selected row. When I use command from popup menu or shortcut it works as expected, but when I use double-click to show the dialog, somehow my mouse-move events are skepped until I make a click inside the dialog. I guess that mouse-up event from the second click is send incorectly to dialog not to main window.

Currently I'm using following hack:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_doubleClicked ( const QModelIndex& )
{
    QTimer::singleShot ( 100, this, SLOT ( on_macEdit_triggered() ) );
}
```

The delyed trigering for 100ms gives enought time for the double-click event to complete its work, and then the dialog is displayed with working mouse-move events.

Is there a better way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you set the appropriate edit triggers? https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop

Comment: @cmannett85: Yes. Actually, the data will be edited in the dialog, not in the table, and `editTriggers` is set to `NoEditTriggers`.